# Jetpack Compose Tests cause "java.lang.IllegalStateException: no event up from DESTROYED" when run in succession

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose, android-instrumentation

I have instrumented tests I'm running on an application using Jetpack Compose. The tests pass independently, but when run in succession, I receive:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: no event up from DESTROYED

along with a call stack including some lines in my entry-point composable that seem to indicate that the NavController implementation is to blame. The issue isn't reproducible in the non-instrumented build running on the same device so I have a feeling it's how I'm implementing the AppState creation in the @Before function. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no event up from DESTROYED
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:263)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:121)
at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.updateState(NavBackStackEntry.kt:173)
at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.handleLifecycleEvent(NavBackStackEntry.kt:157)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.lifecycleObserver$lambda-2(NavController.kt:184)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.$r8$lambda$QcvT-AhOyhL9f0B2nrlZ1aMydmQ(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.navigation.NavController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onStateChanged(Unknown Source:2)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
**at androidx.navigation.NavController.setLifecycleOwner(NavController.kt:2119)**
at androidx.navigation.NavHostController.setLifecycleOwner(NavHostController.kt:54)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:105)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:69)
**at com.roadbytes.ui.main.RoadBytesAppKt$CreateRoadBytesApp$1$2.invoke(RoadBytesApp.kt:198)
at com.roadbytes.ui.main.RoadBytesAppKt$CreateRoadBytesApp$1$2.invoke(RoadBytesApp.kt:196)**
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1$bodyContentPlaceables$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:316)
at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1$bodyContentPlaceables$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:314)
```

The setup function is like so:

```
@Before
fun setupAppWithFakes() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val tripsRepo = FirebaseRepo(
            emulate = true,
            firebaseDBPath = resources.getString(R.string.db_path_trips),
            logTag = resources.getString(R.string.log_tag_trips_repo),
            entityFactory = TripFactory())
        val appState = RoadBytesAppState.getInstance(
            with(RoadBytesAppState){
                mapOf(
                    this.CONTEXT_KEY to LocalContext.current,
                    this.NAV_CONTROLLER_KEY to navController,
                    this.AUTH_HANDLER_KEY to authHandlerFake,
                    this.TRIPS_REPO_KEY to tripsRepo
                )
            }
        )
        CreateRoadBytesApp(appState)
    }
    composeTestRule.waitForIdle()
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(tripsNavButtonTag).performClick()
}
```

My entry-point composable is:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun CreateRoadBytesApp(
    appState: RoadBytesAppState
) {
    RoadBytesTheme {
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = { RoadBytesBottomNavBar(appState, Screens.navigableScreens()) }
        ) { innerPadding ->
            NavHost(
                navController = appState.navController,
                startDestination = Screens.RecordTripScreen.route,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
            ){
                composable(Screens.RecordTripScreen.route) { RecordTripScreen(appState) }
                composable(Screens.SignInScreen.route) { SignInScreen(appState) }
                composable(Screens.SignUpScreen.route) { SignUpScreen(appState) }
                composable(Screens.TripsScreen.route) { TripsScreen(appState) }
                composable(Screens.VehiclesScreen.route) { VehiclesScreen(appState) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see the issue at a first glance. I have written an [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-optimize-firebase-realtime-database-calls-to-improve-performance-cc63dad374d5) about the Realtime Database and Jetpack Compose, maybe it will help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using createComposeRule() instead of createAndroidComposeRule(MainActivity). Double check the following dependencies to the build.gradle file of the module containing your UI tests: especially **androidTestImplementation** and **debugImplementation**

```
// Test rules and transitive dependencies:
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version")
// Needed for createComposeRule, but not createAndroidComposeRule:
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version")
```

[Testing your Compose layout  |  Jetpack Compose  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#setup)